# Add a single Bash command

Tags: bash

I do not have su access and I have a perl executable in **~/et** directory which is called **exiftool**.

I need to add that executable to bash commands (so that I can type **exiftool** instead of **~/et/exiftool**).

The problem is that **~/et** contains other files that are not executable (so I cannot use **export  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/et**). Is there any alternative?

Comment: Actually you can add ~/et to your PATH even if there are non-executable files in there.  Bash is smart enough to not execute them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an alias:

```
alias exiftool=~/et/exiftool
```

Or you can symlink it elsewhere and add *that* directory to your path:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
ln -s ~/et/exiftool ~/bin
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Any method that uses `PATH` is preferable, be it symlinking as described or installing executables into a `bin` directory.

Comment: Why symlink?  just move the file into ~/bin

Comment: I'm assuming there's some reason for it to be in ~/et

Comment: PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH does search in bin before default path? Or vice versa?

Comment: Anathor question: is it normal that when I type "README" I get -bash: /home/collimarco/et/README: Permission denied ?

Comment: @collimarco, that searches $HOME/bin first. And, if you are ~/et to your path and it has a non-executable README, you might well get such errors.

Comment: Just don't make a text file in /home/collimarco/et/ and call it ls or something :)

Comment: @bdonlan 
$ cd ~
$ README
-bash: /home/collimarco/et/README: Permission denied

@Eugene There are a lot of files and some of the can not be moved because they are part of the application

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why having files that are not executable in the directory prevents you from adding the directory to your PATH anyway?

As an alternative, though, you can use an alias.

```
alias exiftool=$HOME/et/exiftool
```

You can place this in your .bashrc to have it always available.

Answer (score 0):

1. softlink to a folder in PATH
2. alias exiftool='~/et/exiftool'